# Einstein's Sorter

Tags: code-golf, array, date, sorting, physics

### Challenge

Given a list of integers and a velocity, \$v\$, implement a sorting algorithm which simulates a program sorting the list from smallest to biggest at the given velocity.

### Einstein's Theory of Special Relativity

What do I mean? Well assume your program takes a time, \$T\$, to sort a particular list. If you ran the program again at a higher velocity, \$v\$, according to a stationary observer your program would run slower and would take a different time, \$T'\$, to sort the same list.

How do you relate \$T\$ to \$T'\$? You use the equation for time dilation:

$$T' = \frac{T}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

If we use geometrised units where \$v\$ is a fraction of the speed of light, and \$0\leq v \lt 1\$.

So you must change your program's running time by a factor of

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

### Output

You must output the sorted list

### Rules

- You are allowed an error of \$\pm0.1 \text{ s}\$
- The length of the list, \$l\$, will be in the range \$1 \leq l \leq 50\$
- The list will contain only integers
- The velocity will be given in geometrised units
- You may sort the list then wait before outputting

### Examples

For these examples, assume my program takes a time of \$T = l^2 \text{ s}\$ to run, where \$l\$ is the length of the list, regardless of the contents of the list:

```
List, Velocity > Sorted list, Time taken
[9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1], 0.5 > [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 93.5307
[8,0,0,5,6], 0.1 > [0,0,5,6,8], 25.1259
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7], 0.999 > [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7], 453.684
```

Your timings do not need to be as accurate.

### Winning

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Suppose your program sorts a list `L` in time `T` in the 'normal' rest frame (`v=0`). Then, if we run with the same list `L` with `v=sqrt(0.5)`, how long should your program take to run? `2*T` or `3*T` or some other number?

Comment: Perhaps use the [tag:time] or [tag:restricted-time] tags?

Comment: @ChasBrown your program should take `T/sqrt(1-v**2)` to run. For `v=sqrt(0.5)`, then your program should run for `sqrt(2)*T`

Comment: @ChasBrown If your program runs for a time `T`,  then it should pause for a time of `T/sqrt(1-v**2) - T`

Comment: @Beta Decay: I agree with your latter comment ("... should pause... - T"); but your previous with "should run for `sqrt(2)*T`..." still seems a bit off, computationally...

Comment: @ChasBrown What do you mean?

Comment: @Beta Decay: I mean that, given that `v=0` your program runs for `T`; then "For `v=sqrt(0.5)`, then your program should run for `sqrt(2)*T`" is not correct as a calculation. However, more generally,  "If your program runs for a time `T` (with `v=0`), then it should pause for a time of `T/sqrt(1-v**2) - T`" is correct, as a calculation.

Comment: @ChasBrown Overall your program should run for `T' = T/sqrt(1-v**2)`. The sorting section of the program will run for `T`, so the pausing section of the program will run for `T/sqrt(1-v**2) - T`. When `v=sqrt(0.5)`, then the program as a whole should run for `T' = T/sqrt(1-0.5) = sqrt(2) * T`. When `v=0` then the program as a whole will run for `T' = T/sqrt(1-0) = T`. I'm still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Beta Decay: I see now; you're correct.

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

<sup>-1 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma?tab=profile) (using `z` instead of pushing 1)</sup>

```bash
for n in $2;{
sleep `dc -e"9k$n z$1d*-v/f"`&&echo $n&
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxDoIwFAbgnVP8waaDCQo4GU7g5OIBKPSRNpaW8FqbaDx79Ru@SbEpZQk7PKyH6IdPxY5ow6hnNFRfn8LjLTp9bF7npR6lpNkECC@rb8nKRuCAbKMJKSIay/8Ij9sdKylOO63kIyOH5DQmwhasj46YS2lPbbmgQ/8D)

#### Explanation

Sleep sort loops over all the integers, for each \$n\$ it does the following in the background:

- set a timer of \$n\$ seconds (or another time unit)
- print \$n\$

Instead of using one second we divide \$n\$ by \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\$ which is achieved by the following dc code:

```bash
9k              # set precision to 9 digits
  $n            # push n                    [n]
     z          # push size of stack        [1,n]
      $1        # push v                    [v,1,n]
        d*      # duplicate & multiply      [v^2,1,n]
          -     # subtract                  [1-v^2,n]
           v    # square root               [sqrt(1-v^2),n]
            /   # divide                    [n/sqrt(1-v^2)]
             f  # print
```

Comment: [A couple of bytes off](https://tio.run/##DcQxDoIwFAbgnVP8waaDCQo4GU7g5OIBKPSRNpaW8FqbaDx79Ru@SbEpZQk7PKyH6IdPxY5ow6hnNFRfn8K/RaePzeu81KOUNJsA4WX1LVnZCByQbTQhRURj@R/hcbtjJcVpp5V8ZOSQnMZE2IL10RFzKe2pLRd06H8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 91 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>

```python
from time import*
def f(l,v):t=time();s=sorted(l);d=time()-t;sleep(d/(1-v*v)**.5-d);print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3NCsIwEITveYqlF5PQ1h8QscEnEQ9CEgzkj@xS8OljixVKD87CHGaGb/ObXimearUlBSAXDLiQUyHJtLFguW9HMdBtbrhQeMOpM5p7ofQSdqTQG5O53vNjN8pRSNmfOy1ULi4SYMVlyb5BE1MJTw8zCoaGWX6/tKt7tHD4bZcXyNgWYlxEmmyHf0H9daUttX4A)

Comment: `print` instead of `return` should, as usual in Python 2, save a byte.

Comment: Suppose `v=.5**.5`; then `1/(1-v*v)**.5 = 2`; and suppose the actual sort takes `T=time()-t` seconds. Your function then takes a total of `3*T` seconds to complete, which is too long; it should only take `2*T` seconds. So I think you want something like: `u=(1-v*v)**.5;sleep((time()-t)*(1-u)/(u))`.

Comment: @ChasBrown hmm, I followed the OP's equation

Comment: @Rod: I've asked the question to OP. They key to me is when `v=0`, it should take the same amount of time as it would just to sort the list normally with none of this funny business; but using the (not unreasonable) interpretation you give, it would take twice that long.

Comment: @ChasBrown I realised the error now, fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 52 bytes

```apl
{t←2⊃⎕AI⋄r←⍵[⍋⍵]⋄r⊣⎕DL 1e¯3×s-(s←t-2⊃⎕AI)÷.5*⍨1-⍺*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqEiBh9Kir@VHfVEfPR90tRUD@o96t0Y96u4FULFikazFQ1sVHwTD10Hrjw9OLdTWKgapKdOH6NA9v1zPVetS7wlD3Ue8uLaPa//8NDQwetU1UMNCztLRUSFMwNEg1tTdMNQcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 168 bytes

```
import StdEnv,System.Time,System._Unsafe,Debug.Performance
?u=:(Clock m,l)n#!(Clock i)=accUnsafe clock
|toReal i>toReal m*1E4/sqrt(one-n*n)=l= ?u n
```

```
?o(measureTime sort)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NSgNBEITv@xQtueyGzToBLyuMOZgcBA/B1ZOItJPeMDjdo/MjBHx2xyyJeKv6qIIq4wilsN9lR8BopVj@8CHBkHYb@WqHQ0zE3aNl@tOvTxJxpHZNb3nfbSmMPjCKoWqV9XV967x5B25dI7OLs7ONRmNOPTATqr6TfyB0YG/OgufLzdVl/Ayp9kILmUujnYZVBilDwpCqGYxZTLJe4Mh9zYQxB5q2QTxubir9n3heKqXavu@7Tr2A6lT5MaPDfSyLu/uyPgiyNSezdZimD78)

A composed function literal which times the sorting of the list, and then loops until an appropriate additional number of ticks have passed.